# Multilanguage not working for headless | Sitecore NextJs URLs throw 404 for non English locale

Tags: jss, multilingual, nextjs

URLs throw 404 when trying with another language, it's only working for en.
I can see the JSON response for it when accessing the API.

I have added language in CMS, setup the page for it and also added it to next.config.js

```
i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr-FR'],
    defaultLocale: packageConfig.language,
  },
```

Does anyone know if I'm missing something?

`Sitecore version - 10.3`
`Frontend Framework - NextJs`

Comment: Have you published your page?

Comment: @RishirajShekhawat I've web pointed to master database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to export static files with `next export`, it will not work. It's implicitly marked as a limitation in [the docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/201/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--exporting-a-jss-next-js-app-to-static-html-files-with-next-export.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm trying to access the URLs in connected mode.